# PostgreSQL timestamp after converting to date, return date value - 01/01/1970

Tags: php, postgresql, date

After inserting data from pstgrsql database I need to convert timestamp to date.
I tried php date() function but I only got value - 01/01/1970. Here is example of my code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM \"user\"  WHERE verified= 't'";

$result = pg_query($conn, $query);

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {

$date = date('d/m/Y', $row[11]);

echo "\n";
echo "$row[0] , $row[1] , $row[3], $date ";

}

$ReportRow = array('date' => $date, 'activereg' => $activerag);
$ReportRow1 = array('date' => $date);
$ReportRow2 = array('date' => $date);

$report = array($ReportRow, $ReportRow1, $ReportRow2);
```

*there will be more data stored in these arrays but its just work in progress for now. Thanks all for any kind responses :)

**EDIT 1**

DB has rows like

```
`3125, alex, alex@example.com, 01/01/1970`
```

Comment: give us a test row return value.

Comment: row have values like: username, pass, etc.... and timestamp when was registration confirmed, output looks like this: http://prntscr.com/fc2ozc (id, username, email, timestamp)

Comment: @ShawnMehan thank you for your time, it worked well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `date()` to try to convert a string into a date, when `date` only accepts a full timestamp.

```
date(format,timestamp);
```

Rather, you want to convert your string in your `result` into a `time` value. Try

```
$time = strtotime($row[11]);
```

and if you need to switch it about use

```
$newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);
```

If you need a timestamp after that, you can

```
$timestamp = $time->getTimestamp(); // Unix timestamp
```